# Python store ZIP file enclosures from an RSS feed into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, rss, zip, python-2.x

Guys i have this code which locates the ZIP enclosure in an RSS feed.

```
def labrat(feed):
    for item in feed.entries:
        try:
            # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
            enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ]
            if ( len( enclosures ) > 0 ):
                # ZIP file enclosure exists, so we can just download the ZIP file
                enclosure = enclosures[0]
        except:
            pass
```

The problem is that the module only inputs the first zip enclosure in the variable `enclosure[0]`. However there are as many as 100 - 150 ZIP enclosures per RSS feed.

How can i store **every** ZIP file enclosure in the variable `enclosure` and access it by typing `enclosures[0]` for the first ZIP file enclosure, `enclosures[1]` for the second ZIP file enclosure etc.

**EDIT**

Can you show some entries as an example? by [sundar nataraj Сундар](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545322/sundar-nataraj-%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80)

**A:EDIT**

```
>>> enclosure
{'length': '125413', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104207/000010420711000005/0000104207-11-000005-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}
```

OR equivalently

```
>>> enclosures[0]
{'length': '125413', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104207/000010420711000005/0000104207-11-000005-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}
```

**EDIT_2**
Under request i am putting a chunk of the RSS Feed

```
[{'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/0000316793-11-000013-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '10', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/0000316793-11-000013-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '75194', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/0000316793-11-000013-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '3674', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 17:20:59 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0000316793-11-000013', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '001-07935', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=22, tm_min=20, tm_sec=59, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'INTERNATIONAL RECTIFIER CORP /DE/', 'title': 'INTERNATIONAL RECTIFIER CORP /DE/ (0000316793) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-Q', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101226', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'INTERNATIONAL RECTIFIER CORP /DE/ (0000316793) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-Q', 'edgar_formtype': '10-Q', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0000316793', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/0000316793-11-000013-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '0628', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '11', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/logo.jpg', 'file': 'logo.jpg', 'description': 'LOGO', 'type': 'graphic', 'edgar:file': 'logo.jpg', 'edgar:description': 'LOGO', 'edgar:type': 'GRAPHIC', 'size': '8465', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316793/000031679311000013/logo.jpg', 'edgar:size': '8465', 'sequence': '11'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131172059'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/0000950123-11-007372-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '3', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/0000950123-11-007372-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '69503', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/0000950123-11-007372-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '7372', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 17:10:25 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0000950123-11-007372', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '033-41752', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=22, tm_min=10, tm_sec=25, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'PROGRESS SOFTWARE CORP /MA', 'title': 'PROGRESS SOFTWARE CORP /MA (0000876167) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-K', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101130', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'PROGRESS SOFTWARE CORP /MA (0000876167) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-K', 'edgar_formtype': '10-K', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0000876167', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/0000950123-11-007372-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '1130', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '13', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/b83530b8353001.gif', 'file': 'b83530b8353001.gif', 'description': 'GRAPHIC', 'type': 'graphic', 'edgar:file': 'b83530b8353001.gif', 'edgar:description': 'GRAPHIC', 'edgar:type': 'GRAPHIC', 'size': '18513', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876167/000095012311007372/b83530b8353001.gif', 'edgar:size': '18513', 'sequence': '13'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131171025'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/0000950123-11-007291-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '6', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/0000950123-11-007291-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '109861', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/0000950123-11-007291-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '1531', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 16:45:12 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0000950123-11-007291', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '001-09195', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=21, tm_min=45, tm_sec=12, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'KB HOME', 'title': 'KB HOME (0000795266) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-K', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101130', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'KB HOME (0000795266) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-K', 'edgar_formtype': '10-K', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0000795266', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/0000950123-11-007291-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '1130', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '19', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/filename19.htm', 'file': 'filename19.htm', 'description': '', 'type': 'cover', 'edgar:file': 'filename19.htm', 'edgar:description': '', 'edgar:type': 'COVER', 'size': '1367', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/795266/000095012311007291/filename19.htm', 'edgar:size': '1367', 'sequence': '19'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131164512'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/0001193125-11-018957-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '6', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/0001193125-11-018957-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '152273', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/0001193125-11-018957-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '1520', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 16:43:34 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0001193125-11-018957', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '001-11749', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=21, tm_min=43, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'LENNAR CORP /NEW/', 'title': 'LENNAR CORP /NEW/ (0000920760) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-K', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101130', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'LENNAR CORP /NEW/ (0000920760) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-K', 'edgar_formtype': '10-K', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0000920760', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/0001193125-11-018957-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '1130', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '29', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/g127281g62x94.jpg', 'file': 'g127281g62x94.jpg', 'description': 'GRAPHIC', 'type': 'graphic', 'edgar:file': 'g127281g62x94.jpg', 'edgar:description': 'GRAPHIC', 'edgar:type': 'GRAPHIC', 'size': '33783', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000119312511018957/g127281g62x94.jpg', 'edgar:size': '33783', 'sequence': '29'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131164334'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/0001206264-11-000004-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '6', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/0001206264-11-000004-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '85162', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/0001206264-11-000004-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '2510', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 16:22:00 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0001206264-11-000004', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '001-31922', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=21, tm_min=22, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'TEMPUR PEDIC INTERNATIONAL INC', 'title': 'TEMPUR PEDIC INTERNATIONAL INC (0001206264) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-K', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101231', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'TEMPUR PEDIC INTERNATIONAL INC (0001206264) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-K', 'edgar_formtype': '10-K', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0001206264', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/0001206264-11-000004-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '1231', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '13', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/tpx-20101231.xml', 'file': 'tpx-20101231.xml', 'description': 'EX-101.INS', 'type': 'ex-101.ins', 'edgar:file': 'tpx-20101231.xml', 'edgar:description': 'EX-101.INS', 'edgar:type': 'EX-101.INS', 'size': '913029', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1206264/000120626411000004/tpx-20101231.xml', 'edgar:size': '913029', 'sequence': '13'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131162200'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/0000790730-11-000007-xbrl.zip', 'edgar_xbrlfiling': '', 'edgar_xbrlfiles': '', 'edgar_assistantdirector': '6', 'links': [{'type': 'text/html', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/0000790730-11-000007-index.htm', 'rel': 'alternate'}, {'length': '113260', 'type': 'application/zip', 'href': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/0000790730-11-000007-xbrl.zip', 'rel': 'enclosure'}], 'edgar_assignedsic': '3270', 'published': 'Mon, 31 Jan 2011 16:17:09 EST', 'edgar_accessionnumber': '0000790730-11-000007', 'guidislink': False, 'edgar_filenumber': '001-09102', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=21, tm_min=17, tm_sec=9, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0), 'edgar_companyname': 'AMERON INTERNATIONAL CORP', 'title': 'AMERON INTERNATIONAL CORP (0000790730) (Filer)', 'summary_detail': {'value': '10-K', 'type': 'text/html', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'edgar_period': '20101130', 'edgar_filingdate': '01/31/2011', 'title_detail': {'value': 'AMERON INTERNATIONAL CORP (0000790730) (Filer)', 'type': 'text/plain', 'base': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2011-01.xml', 'language': None}, 'summary': '10-K', 'edgar_formtype': '10-K', 'edgar_ciknumber': '0000790730', 'link': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/0000790730-11-000007-index.htm', 'edgar_fiscalyearend': '1130', 'edgar_xbrlfile': {'edgar:sequence': '16', 'url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/amn-20101130_def.xml', 'file': 'amn-20101130_def.xml', 'description': 'AMERON XBRL 10-K DEFINITION', 'type': 'ex-101.def', 'edgar:file': 'amn-20101130_def.xml', 'edgar:description': 'AMERON XBRL 10-K DEFINITION', 'edgar:type': 'EX-101.DEF', 'size': '23665', 'edgar:url': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/790730/000079073011000007/amn-20101130_def.xml', 'edgar:size': '23665', 'sequence': '16'}, 'edgar_acceptancedatetime': '20110131161709'}, {'id': 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/53669/000095012311007182/00
```

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар i have modified my answer. If you need the whole `feed.entries` please tel me

Comment: sec i typed the command it is parsing i will input an big excerpt momentarily

Comment: Dear friends i have posted a big piece of the RSS Feed

Comment: can you post it on pastebin or similar? seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def labrat(feed):
    totalEnclosure=[]
    for item in feed.entries:
        try:
            # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
            enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ]
            if ( len( enclosures ) > 0 ):
                # ZIP file enclosure exists, so we can just download the ZIP file
                totalEnclosure.extend(enclosures)
        except:
            pass
     print totalEnclosure
```

Please try to append all the enclosures to a list.

Comment: I ve tried it and it does not print out anything, why put `enclosures[0]` dont we want an index to increment there?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant try this one now

Comment: does `enclosures` contains the data you want saved?

Comment: the data that i want to be saved exist in `feed.entries` and this modules extracts them from it. These are the `ZIP File enclosures`. I need every enclosure inside the `enclosures` variable. For example `enclosures[0]` --> first enclosure etc

Comment: I have tested the new code sundar it prints out nothing snif

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary with an integer that will be the key to find items in in, basically you're emulating something like a C array:

```
def labrat(feed):

    # the index you will refer to
    index = 0
    # the "array"
    enclosure = {}
    for item in feed.entries:
        try:
            # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
            enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ]
            if ( len( enclosures ) > 0 ):
                # ZIP file enclosure exists, so we can just download the ZIP file
                enclosure[index] = enclosures
                index += 1
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Yes, maybe lists are a better solution to this problem

Comment: Dear friend i've tested your solution and after i import/execute the funtion if i type: `enclosures[2]` for example i get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    enclosures[2]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: try with enclosures[int(2)], otherwise follow @sundarnatarajСундар advice and implement a similar logic with lists

Comment: `enclosures[int(2)]` returns `IndexError: list index out of range` which is the same error. I will try also to find out how to do it with a list

Comment: posting a big excerpt from the feed just a sec

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant try printing out that dict and see how many entries there are, that errors means that there isn't any entry with key "2"

Comment: @PeppeLaKappa i cannot understand since it is a loop that iterates every ZIP enclosure in the RSS Feed why cant it just put every ZIP enclosure in a variable and then have accessibility by just typing the var and an index number?

Comment: try now, maybe it was my fault by swapping enclosures with enclosure